# android : Service member variables becomes null after application closed

Tags: android, sockets, android-fragments, android-intent, android-service

In my application, I have activity and service, activity called `startService` and `bindservice` (for communication between service and activity).

In service `socket communication` is getting initialized and also one `Messanger handler` initialized for give back reply to activity. It is working fine when application is up and running.

Once application is closed forcefully by user then service started again automatically that I can see in logcat. Here socket also initialized. But `Messanger handler` is still null as it was previously initialized by `mMyService.setHandler(handler)` method which is calling from activity but this time its called when service restarted automatically.

How Can I make communication between activity and service after application gets closed. Service is running but activity is in died state.

Please help me. I spent a lot of time in this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to happen? If the app is forcefully closed, then the activities are all gone.

Comment: @DavidWasser  yes correct. Activities are all gone and my service has been restarted as I have used STICKY. Now how can I do communication between Service and Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have force closed the app, you can't communicate with the Activity. It is gone. Dead.

What you could do is recognize the situation (for example, you can check if `handler == null` and if so you could launch the Activity automatically from the Service, like this:

```
if (handler == null) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to apply this workaround